# Minifying and Concatenate Scripts, should I save jQuery locally or Google host and modify concatenation code

Tags: vb.net, performance, concatenation, scriptmanager

Quite  along question title, because the question is quite long.

I've been looking at ways to improve the speed of my site and web app.

Last night, I came across this article:

http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/Languages/.NET/ASP.NET/A_4334-Minify-and-Concatenate-Your-Scripts-and-Stylesheets.html

I've implemented the code this morning and I am pleased to say, at first glance it appears to be very good.

The only snag is that it can only concatenate locally hosted scripts. I generally use the Google hosted versions of jQuery and sometimes a couple other scripts that are widely used. (Given that a lot of users will have this file cached anyway... I presume)

I am not entirely sure what the concatenate code is doing, so trying to work out how to modify it... or... should I just download the jQuery file and host locally, then it'll just work!

I can post some code here, but obviously, there's quite a lot, so I thought I'd try and get a general opinion first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMO, it's not worth aggregating in a Google-hosted jQuery.  This is already aggregated and minified.  Just concentrate on applying this technique to scripts that your server hosts.  Your browser will load them in parallel if not already cached anyway.

Comment: Agreed... after spending a lot of the day messing around trying to do it!!